# Malformed AWS policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hey I'm getting a very non-verbose error here about a malformed policy (this is a Terraform template, incase you want to question the variables). Anyway, thanks.

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement":[{
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":[
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
      ],
        "Resource":[
          "arn:aws:s3:::*"
      ],
    "Effect":"Allow"
  }, {
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action":[
      "s3:ListBucket",
      "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
    ],
    "Resource":[
      "arn:aws:s3:::${bucket_name}"
    ],
      "Effect":"Allow"
    }, {
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":[
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
        "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl"
      ],
      "Resource":[
        "arn:aws:s3:::${bucket_name}/*"
      ],
      "Effect":"Allow"
  }]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the template is being filled in before sending to AWS?

Comment: Positive, it shows in the TF output

Answer (score 0):

I had an extra `name` in my terraform module